# particle moving through a flow of liquid, speed of liquid is uniform

Tags: analysis, functions, solution-verification

Consider the steady flow of a fluid (that is, the velocity at each point of the flow does not change over time). In time t a particle at point x of the flow will move to some new point $f_{t}(x)$ of space. The mapping $x↦f_t(x)$ that arises thereby on the points of space occupied by the flow depends on time and is called the mapping after time t. Show that $f_{t2}∘f_{t1}=f_{t1}∘f_{t2}=f_{t1}+t_2$ and $f_t∘f_{−t}=e_X$.

My attempt:
Let $f_t$ be defined as $f_t(x) = x + vt$. Then $$f_{t2} \circ f_{t1} = f_{t2}(x+vt_1) = (x+vt_1)+vt_2$$
$$f_{t_1} \circ f_{t_2}(x) = f_{t_1}(x+vt_2) = (x+vt_2)+vt_1$$
$$f_{t_1+t_2}(x) = x + v(t_1+t_2) = x + vt_1 +vt_2$$
$$f_t \circ f_{-t}(x) = f_t(x + (-vt)) = (x-vt) + vt = x$$

Does this resemble the truth? Not sure about "$f_t$ being defined as $f_t(x) = x + vt$" being correct in particular, but logically seems sound I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solution is incorrect, since you cannot assume that the velocity $v$ is constant. We can assume we have a velocity field $v(x)$ (which doesn't depend on $t$), and thus

$x'(t) = v(x)$

Is a regular autonomous ODE of the first order, which it's solution is given by

$f_t(x) = x(t) = x(0) + \int_0^t v(x(a))da$

Now we can go on to prove your exercise -

$ x(s) = x(0) + \int_0^s v(x(a))da$

Solving the ODE again with the initial condition $x(s)$ and predicting the solution at time $t$ gives

$ x(t+s) = x(s) + \int_s^t v(x(a))da $

Substituting $x(s)$ from the original formula gives

$ x(t+s) = x(0) + \int_0^s v(x(a))da + \int_s^t v(x(a))da = x(0) + \int_0^{t+s} v(x(a))da $

which is consistent with what you wish to prove - $f_{t+s} = f_t \circ f_s$. The rest of the computations are similar.

Comment: Thank you! I see my error. Sorry for making you answer again, but I was wondering if this can be solved without using differential equations? Since the book hasn't even introduced differentials and integrals yet, much less ODEs, the only things covered so far were functions and relations. Although maybe it was a question for the more mathematically versed students.

Comment: The nature of the question is really ODE-related, as they are talking about velocity.. I don't know if you can even start talking about velocity without defining derivatives and other things formally. Maybe the idea was to make you think "more intuitively" of the subject, but the assumption of a constant velocity is (most probably) not what the author intended.

Comment: Yes, I agree that constant velocity is not what he intended. Thanks again!